# Method in event handlers are not called in SignalR after some time

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

On starting, the application with SignalR 2 implementation works as expected. But after sometime (it can be after 5 minutes or 30 minutes or 10 minutes), the events are not called anymore. But the Server and Client are still connected. I know it is connected because it the trace level of the client for SignalR, it can still get the commands coming from the Server.

[image]

But my messages from my client is still being received by the server and its action executed so I know that the Server - Client connection is still good.

Also, I know that it is still connected because I always check the status of the connection.

This is how I implement the SignalR

```
public void ConnectAsync()
    {
        WriteToLogs("Connecting to Server...");
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "UserName", _signalrSettings.ApplicationName } };
        _hubConnection?.Dispose();
        _hubConnection = new HubConnection(_signalrSettings.ServerUri, dic);
        _hubConnection.StateChanged += Connection_StateChanged;
        _hubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(_signalrSettings.HubProxy);
        try
        {
            _hubProxy.On<string, string>("Initial", (a, b) => Initial());
           
            _hubConnection.Start().ContinueWith((s) =>
            {
                if (s.IsCompleted)
                {
                    _isCompleted = true;
                }
                else if (s.IsCanceled)
                {
                    _isCompleted = false;
                }
                else if (s.IsFaulted)
                {
                    _isCompleted = false;
                }
                _hubProxy.On<string, string>("NewMessage", (userName, message) => NewMessage(userName, message)); // THE "NewMessage" is not fired after some time.
                WriteToLogs( $@"Connection status is {_hubConnection.State}");
            }).Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var trace = new StackTrace(e, true);

            var reflectedType = trace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().ReflectedType;
            if (reflectedType != null)
            {
                _messageOperation.WriteErrors($@"Error {e.StackTrace} at {trace}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "SignalR 2 implementation" Specifically, what version of SignalR are you using? And it is 2 .x for .NET Framework 4.x or .NET Core x?

Comment: @FrankM
It' this one

Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core
Version 2.2.1.0
Runtinme Version v4.0.30319

Comment: With that version (for .NET 4.x Framework) you are going to want to upgrade to 2.4.3. There were issues due to browser changes that stopped updating if they were not focused after a period of time. These were fixed in 2.4.2. https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/4536

Comment: If I upgrade the Signal version of the server, would the clients need to upgrade their SignalR version as well? If they have the lower version, can they still connect? Btw, the applications are not web based. All of them are console based.

Comment: Usually recommended to upgrade both. This should not be major change since you are already on 2.2.1. I did not see before that they were console based. I would still upgrade as there are probably other bug fixes between the versions that might correct behavior.

Comment: This makes absolute sense, problem is; I have no access to the source code of the clients. With this situation, if I adjust the SignalR version of the "server", would there be any issues with the clients?

Comment: It's possible that would be an issue. I have never not updated both.